# C#で文字列の抽出

Tags: c#, 正規表現

C#でテキストファイルから5文字以上の数字があれば読み込みその前後10文字と数字を抜き出したいのですが、うまくいきません。。

```
string file = textBox1.Text;
string pattern_count = @"[0-9]{5,}";

IEnumerable<string> files =System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(@file, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);


foreach (string f in files)
{

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f, Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS"));
    string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();

    if (str.Contains(pattern_count))
    {

        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r =new  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@pattern_count ,System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection m = r.Matches(f);

        while (m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
            m = m.NextMatch();
        }                                      

    }

}
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12190064202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> その前後10文字と数字を抜き出したい

[Matchクラス](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx)にはIndexプロパティとLengthプロパティがあります。これらを使用することで、元文字列のどの位置がマッチしたのかを知ることができます。これを利用すれば実現できると思います。

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(textBox1.Text, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
    var str = File.ReadAllText(file, Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS"));
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(str, "[0-9]{5,}")) {
        var begin = Math.Max(m.Index - 10, 0);
        var end = Math.Min(m.Index + m.Length + 10, str.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(begin, end - begin));
    }
}
```

オフセット計算が間違っていたらすみません（’’

Comment: ありがとうございました。わかりました

Answer (score 1):

質問のコードがコンパイルできないのは

> ```
>    System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection m = r.Matches(f);
>
>     while (m.Success)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
>         m = m.NextMatch();
>     }
> ```

でマッチに使用している`Regex.Matches`メソッドと繰り返し処理で使用している`while (m.Success) ～ m = m.NextMatch();`の方針が一致していないからです。つまり`Matches`の戻り値は`MatchCollection`ですが、下のループは`m`が`Match`型であることを想定したアルゴリズムになっています。

ですので`Matches`メソッドと`m`の型を`Match`に変更するか、`Matches`の戻り値を`foreach`で処理するかに統一する必要があります。

```
Match m = r.Match(f);
```

また上記以前にも不具合があります。

> ```
> if (str.Contains(pattern_count))
> ```

この`pattern_count`は正規表現ですが、`String.Contains`は単純に文字列として検索をするため、数字5文字ではこの条件を満たしません。この分岐は単純に削除して正規表現に任せればよいでしょう。